# webHDFS API returns Exception on every query

Tags: rest, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I setuped single node Hadoop cluster to perform some experiments with HDFS. Via web access all looks good, I created a dedicated folder and copied file from local system to it using command line. It all appeared in web UI. After it I to get access to it via WebHDFS.
For example:

```
curl -i "http://127.0.0.1:50075/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS"
```

But after that I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 154
Connection: close
{
    "RemoteException":
    {
        "exception":"IllegalArgumentException",
        "javaClassName":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
        "message":"Invalid operation LISTSTATUS"
    }
}
```

The same error I receive on any another command.

I have no idea what went wrong here. Can it be caused for example by missing some components or anything else during setup?

Comment: which hadoop distribution you are using? HDP, CDH or something else?

Comment: For HDP default port for webhdfs is 50070 and curl -i "http://x.x.x.x:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS" works for me

Comment: Thanks it works. I use distribution from official site http://hadoop.apache.org/#Download+Hadoop .

Comment: @SandeshJain your answer worked for me too. You could add it as a proper answer, so OP can mark it as resolved.

Comment: added it as answer, Thank you

Comment: I also want to setup Hadoop web hdfs on ubunto. can you help me out  
  - @AntonRybakov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For HDP you can use following URL (with default port):

> http://x.x.x.x:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=LISTSTATUS

For MapR cluster (with default port):

> http://x.x.x.x:14000/webhdfs/v1/user?op=LISTSTATUS&user.name=YOUR_USER